# What is the difference between color deconvolution and K-means clustering for colors?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, medical

I have some color images needing segmentation.  They are images of slides that are stained with hematoxylin and eosin ("H&E").

I found this method for color deconvolution by Ruifrok

http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/11531144

that separates out the images by color.

However it seems that you can do something similar just by using K-means clustering:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html

I am curious what the difference is.  Any insight would be welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a copy of the article (well without paying) but they are not exactly the same.

**K means seeks** to cluster data. So if you just want to find dominant colors in an image, or do some sorting based on colors, this is the way to go. As a side note: Kmeans can be used on any vector. Its not confined to color, so you can use it for many other applications.

**Color Deconvolution** is trying to remove the effects of chemical dyes commonly used for microscopy. (If I understood the abstract properly). Based on the specific dye used, the algorithm tries to reverse its effects and give you the original color image back (before the dye was added). I found [this website](http://www.mecourse.com/landinig/software/cdeconv/cdeconv.html) that shows some output. This is deconvolving the dye contribution to the RGB spectrum. It doesn't do any clustering/grouping (other than finding the dye)

Hope that helps

**EDIT**
If you didn't know, **convolution** is most often associated with signals/image processing. Basically you take a *filter* and run it over a *signal*. The output is a modified version of the original input. In this case, the original image is filtered by a dye with known RGB values. IF we know the full characteristics of the dye/filter we can invert it. Then by running the convolution again using the inverse filter we can hopefully *de* -convolve the effect. In principle it sounds simple enough, but in many cases this isn't possible.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for taking a look.  Here is the explanation I found of Ruifrok's method:

http://web.hku.hk/~ccsigma/color-deconv/color-deconv.html

If I understand, K-means finds the dominant colors in the image, and then you can separate the image into different color components based on that information, with no prior knowledge of what the stains were.

Ruifrok assumes that the dominant colors are the stain colors, then separates the image by stain.

I guess if K-means works correctly, and you specify that you want two clusters, it ought to pick out the two stains as the two cluster colors.

Comment: You have a correct understanding of kmeans, it needs no apriori knowledge of the data. But deconvolution is more complex than simple kmeans clustering. Think of an example: You have blue cells, you stain w/red dye. The cells are now purple and the background is red. This is your input, the post-dye image (say you get it from a colleague). Your goal is to get the __pre-dye__ image back. K means of 2 yields a cluster for the red portions of the image, and a cluster for the purple cells. Deconvolution removes the color contributions of the red dye, and will show you the original blue cells again.